# Is there a way to quickly change the row number when doing = B1, = B2, ect. for thousands of rows?

Tags: excel-formula, openoffice-calc

This is what I am needing to put into Column A

= B1 & " " & C1 & " " & D1 & " " & E1 & " " & F1 & " " & G1 & " " & H1 & " " & I1

wherein the numbers will correspond to the current row that it is pasted in. Is there a faster way than simply pasting it in and manually changing the 1's to 2's, or to 3's or to 37892's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would string together a bunch of formulas:

```
=INDEX(B:B,Row()) & " " & INDEX(C:C,Row()) & ...
```

But if all you want is to put the formula in J1 and copy it down, then use your original formula.  Put it in J1.  then do one of the following:

- Click on the lower right corner and drag down as far as you want.
- Highlight J1 and all the cells below in which you want the formula.  Go to Fill --> Down

Either of these will automatically change the row number on your original formula.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks!

One thing though, how do I remove the function and have just the text left? I am needing to copy and paste that column into another spreadsheet and then do Text to Columns.

Comment: That is one long way to do a copy paste.  Just copy and paste special the values.

Comment: @damann highlight all the cells you want to copy.  Right click, copy.  Then right click the first cell in which you want to paste. Choose Paste Special.  Then click the Values and  then OK